# Using double quotes for exact matching - how to handle edge cases? (Ex. Odd number of quotes.)

Tags: string, search, pattern-matching, string-matching

## Summary

It's been requested that we add exact matching to the search form on our site.

Below are examples of how we expect the search to operate.

**Example 1**

No exact match has been indicated by the user

Input: `quick brown fox lazy dog`
Output: matches for `quick`, `brown`, `fox`, `lazy`, and `dog`

**Example 2**

"brown" is the exact match indicated by the user

Input: `quick "brown" fox lazy dog`
Output: matches for `quick`, `brown`, `fox`, `lazy`, and `dog` (Same as example 1.)

**Example 3**

"brown fox" is the exact match indicated by the user

Input: `quick "brown fox" lazy dog`
Output: matches for `quick`, `brown fox`, `lazy` and `dog`

**Example 4**

"quick brown" and "lazy dog" are the exact matches indicated by the user

Input: `"quick brown" fox "lazy dog"`
Output: matches for `quick brown`, `fox`, and `lazy dog`

## Question

Now we're trying to determine how edge cases should be handled. Specifically, how should we handle an odd number of quotes (see example 5) and how should we handle double quotes that occur in the middle of words (see example 6 and 7)?

**Example 5**

Odd number of double-quotes

Input: `"quick brown" fox "lazy dog`

Possible Output:

1. Matches for `quick brown`, `fox`, `"lazy`, and `dog` (Use spaces to delimit the search)
2. Matches for `quick brown`, `fox`, `lazy`, and `dog` (Ignore the odd double-quote)
3. Matches for `quick brown`, `fox`, and `lazy dog` (Add a closing double-quote after the last term)

**Example 6**

Even number of quotes, some of which interrupt a word

Input: `qu"ick brown" fox lazy dog`

Possible Output:

1. Matches for `qu`, `ick brown`, `fox`, `lazy`, and `dog` ?
2. (I couldn't think of another way to handle it, but I'm open to ideas.)

**Example 7**

Odd number of quotes, final quote interrupts a word

Input: `"quick brown" fox la"zy dog`

Possible Output:

1. Matches for `quick brown`, `fox`, `la"zy`, and `dog` (Use spaces to delimit the search)
2. Matches for `quick brown`, `fox`, `lazy`, and `dog` (Ignore the odd double-quote)
3. Matches for `quick brown`, `fox`, `la`, and `zy dog` (Add a closing double-quote after the last term)

## Resources

I tried to search for resources that suggest best practices or common practices for these edge cases, but I wasn't able to find anything.

If you know of any resources on this, please let me know.

Comment: If you're going to consider a quote within a word as something special, you could "shift" the quote to include the word it is in the middle of.  And why wouldn't an odd number of quotes be considered an error?

Comment: We could consider it an error, but then what would be displayed to the user? "No results found"? "There was an error in your search"?

I think generally, for a search like this, these cases are handled and the user would never be told there was an error in their search. The back-end would just try to do the search anyway.

Comment: So if it was a typo, the user would have no way of knowing how it affected the search.  And if it wasn't, the user doesn't really know what she is doing, so having the program guess (incorrectly at times) is certainly the way to go.